# Putting all the strings that are in both of two arrays into another array

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, collections, nsarray

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
NSArray * first = @[@"One", @"Two", @"Three"," @Four"];
NSArray * second = @[@"Four", @"Five", @"Six", @"One"];
```

I want to put the objects that are in both into another array:

```
NSArray * both = @[@"Four", @"One"];
```

Is there a more elegant way than going through each item of the first one and checking if its contained in the second?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You basically need to find the intersection of the arrays so you need to use set here:

```
NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:firstArray];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:secondArray]];

NSArray *resultArray = [intersection allObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 instances of `NSMutableSet` from your 2 arrays. Then do:

```
NSArray *result = [[set1 intersectSet:set2] allObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just **use the right tool for the right task.** Alias, use sets for set operations.

```
NSSet *first = [NSSet setWithArray:array1];
NSMutableSet *second = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array2];
[second intersectSet:first];
NSArray *commonObjects = [second allObjects];
```